# Is there any pre-built reddit trend analysis tool?

Tags: social-network-analysis

Basically I want to know what trends there are on Reddit today. Here are what I've looked at and why they don't work:

- [r/popular](https://www.reddit.com/r/popular/) or sites like [Reddit Keyword Research Tool](https://www.highervisibility.com/seo/tools/keyworddit/?) or [Subreddit Stats](https://subredditstats.com/) only return individual hot/trendy/popular submissions, while **a trend may be and usually be mentioned in many submissions, even many subreddits**
- Searching `trend analyse` or `reddit trend` in [r/redditdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/), [r/TheoryOfReddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheoryOfReddit) and [r/dataisbeautiful](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/) doesn't yield satisfied results. Most posts have outdated links or be on very niche topic. The closest thing I get is the post [I made a front page word analyzer - see which words are trending on Reddit. : TheoryOfReddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheoryOfReddit/comments/1cwa6q/i_made_a_front_page_word_analyzer_see_which_words/), but it was 10 years ago and the link is dead.
- [Reddit Insight](https://github.com/PatrickJS/Reddit-Insight/issues/31), [Reddit Unlocked](https://github.com/Parkkeo1/Reddit_Unlocked/issues/1) have bugs to get started. [Pushshift](https://old.reddit.com/r/pushshift/comments/13508r9/pushshift_no_longer_has_access_to_the_reddit_api/) is dead.
- [Reddit Metis](https://redditmetis.com/) is only for user profiles analysis, not trends

Is there any updated, insightful sources on this that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [WhatEvery1Says – WE1S](https://we1s.ucsb.edu/)

Specifically, this project deals with Reddit posts: [A Digital Humanities Study of Reddit Student Discourse about the Humanities – WE1S](https://we1s.ucsb.edu/research_post/a-digital-humanities-study-of-reddit-student-discourse-about-the-humanities/)

Below are some screenshots from the project:

[image]
<sub>Most prominent topics for Humanities and STEM shown in dfr-browser’s Topic View</sub>

[image]
<sub>Topics likely to represent student discourse</sub>

[image]
<sub>Topic 105 in pyLDAvis with Relevance set to 0.6</sub>

Get start by download all [Workspace files](https://zenodo.org/record/5034712), and follow the [documentation](https://whatevery1says.github.io/we1s-templates/).

Since I've had spent some time to study this project, if you are interested to learn more about it as well, you are welcome to contact me and we will share our knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using third-party social media monitoring tools that offer Reddit tracking capabilities. Tools like Brandwatch, Mention, or Hootsuite may have options to monitor Reddit and identify popular discussions and trends. These tools often provide sentiment analysis, engagement metrics, and other useful features for monitoring social media platforms.

Comment: [Reddit Insight](https://github.com/PatrickJS/Reddit-Insight/issues/31) has been dead for a long time. I'm unable to find Reddit Metrics, but there is [Reddit Metis](https://redditmetis.com/). The analysis is cool, but it's only for user profiles, not trends in general